# shell script + match word in line without using echo

Tags: ksh

the following test syntax is part of ksh script

```
   [[ $PARAM = TRUE ]] &&  [[ ` echo $LINE_FROM_FILE | grep -c Validation ` -eq 1 ]] && print "find Validation word"
```

Can I get some other creative syntax/solution/command to verify if Validation word exists in LINE_FROM_FILE without to use the echo command?

LINE_FROM_FILE="123 Validation V125 tcp IP=1.2.56.4"

remark: need to match exactly Validation word

lidia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Parameter expansion` that removes everything up to and including **Validation** and compare that to the normal expansion of the parameter. If they are not equal the parameter contains **Validation**.

```
[[ "${LINE_FROM_FILE##* Validation }" != "${LINE_FROM_FILE}" ]]
```

(Since there are always spaces before and after **Validation** these can be included in the pattern. I do not know of an other way to match beginning and end of word in shell patterns)

Comment: #  LINE_FROM_FILE="1 2 3 ValidationWORD"
#  [[ "${LINE_FROM_FILE##*Validation}" != "${LINE_FROM_FILE}" ]]  && print OK
OK

Comment: try with LINE_FROM_FILE="1 2 3 ValidationWORD" , then you see that its also match -:(

Comment: Your `grep` version would match that line also. What I did was replicate what that version did.

Comment: yes but I want to match exactly the Validation word , I agree that grep not do the Job well

Comment: Are the spaces in front of Validation and after Validation always present?

Comment: yes I have always space before Validation and after Validation word

Comment: In that case the spaces can be included in the pattern. I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using `case`:

```
case $LINE_FROM_FILE in
    *Validation*)
        echo "found word Validation"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "did not find word Validation"
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[ $PARAM = TRUE ]] &&  [[ "$LINE_FROM_FILE" == *Validation* ]] && print "find Validation word"
```